# SQL Server 2000 and 2014 conflicted in client user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2000 on one server, the SQL Server 2014 instance is `DC-SERVER\MSSQL2014` and server name is `DC-SERVER`

I have problem to connect to SQL Server 2000 from client user

On server when I use `DC-SERVER` for connection I have access to SQL Server 2000 and when I use `DC-SERVER\MSSQL2014` I can access SQL Server 2014

But when I'm on a client and use `DC-SERVER`, I only have access to SQL Server 2014 but not to SQL Server 2000.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use `DC-SERVER\MSSQL2014` on the client?

Comment: "SQL SERVER not exist or access denied" error

Comment: Then maybe there's a connectivity issue? Is the 2014 server configured for remote access? Is TCP/IP enabled?

Comment: yes 2014 configed for connect from static ip , and now its work correctly

Comment: but i need reconfig it but i dont know how do it ?